# RQuantlib installation Mac OS X 10.12 Sierra

Tags: r, macos, macos-sierra, quantlib

After having updated Quantlib to version 1.8.1 I fail to reinstall RQuantlib. The installation stops with the following error message:

```
installing to /Users/kliszt/Library/R/3.3/library/RQuantLib/libs
** R
** data
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Users/kliszt/Library/R/3.3/library/RQuantLib/libs/RQuantLib.so':
  dlopen(/Users/kliszt/Library/R/3.3/library/RQuantLib/libs/RQuantLib.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN8QuantLib13FixedRateBondC1EjdRKNS_8ScheduleERKNSt3__16vectorIdNS4_9allocatorIdEEEERKNS_10DayCounterENS_21BusinessDayConventionEdRKNS_4DateERKNS_8CalendarERKNS_6PeriodESK_SE_b
  Referenced from: /Users/kliszt/Library/R/3.3/library/RQuantLib/libs/RQuantLib.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/kliszt/Library/R/3.3/library/RQuantLib/libs/RQuantLib.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Users/kliszt/Library/R/3.3/library/RQuantLib’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RQuantLib’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have tried installing RQuantlib from within R Studio, but also on the command line via

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL RQuantLib_0.4.3.tar.gz
```

but this also fails and results in the same error message. I tried updating R itself, but that didn't help either. Quantlib itself works, I can use it via Python and on the command line it returns the right version.

```
quantlib-config --version
1.8.1
```

Any ideas?

For completeness, here is my session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.12.1 (Sierra)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] rsconnect_0.4.3 tools_3.3.1
```

And the first console output:

```
* installing *source* package ‘RQuantLib’ ...
** package ‘RQuantLib’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for R... yes
checking for quantlib-config... yes
checking for Boost development files... yes
checking for minimal Boost version... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
Completed configuration and ready to build.
...
```

Comment: Read the CRAN page: `OS X Mavericks binaries:  r-release: not available, r-oldrel: not available.` I see no reason to think that Sierra is different than Mavericks.

Comment: Shouldn't I still be able to install from source? `install.packages("RQuantLib", type = "source")` and the command line `R CMD INSTALL RQuantLib_0.4.3.tar.gz` give me the error.

Comment: You might be able to install from source if the external package https://r.research.att.com/libs/QuantLib-1.0.1-darwin9-bin4.tar.gz was installed correctly (meaning probably not with macports or brew) and you have a proper XCode and CLTs installation. Might. The fact that you mentioned none of these details suggests your likelihood of success would be lower.

Comment: You might try looking at prior questions. Looks like Dirk has givne some advice about installing with more recent version of Quantlib than the one avaialble at the ATT website when these were installed with brew.

Comment: CLT were installed and up to date, I tried the external package from ATT, now R studio prompts a different error message: `checking for quantlib-config... yes
configure: WARNING: RQuantLib requires QuantLib (>= 1.4.0).
configure: error: Please upgrade to a current version.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RQuantLib’`

Comment: But still the same error as originally posted when I try to install RQuantLib via the command line: `R CMD INSTALL RQuantLib_0.4.3.tar.gz`